# Extract Scheme and Host from HTTP_REFERER

Tags: php, string

I have `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` — pretend it is http://example.com/i/like/turtles.html. What would I need to do to get just the `http://example.com` part out of the string, and store it in its own variable?

Comment: As a sidenote, just a remark : the Referer is not always sent by the client (it can be disabled, for instance), and it can be faked. So, don't base any critical functionnality (nor security-oriented) on it !

Comment: @PascalMARTIN Sound advice. But, I think a case could be made for examining HTTP_REFERER in $_SERVER (or, using filter_input() / filter_input_array()) from an HTTP POST request.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In this example, the best solution would be to use PHP's [`parse_url` method](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php). This splits up the URL into an associative array. You would then build your final value by combining the `scheme` with the `host`:

```php
if ( $parts = parse_url( "http://example.com/i/like/turtles.html" ) ) {
    echo $parts[ "scheme" ] . "://" . $parts[ "host" ];
}
```

Answer (score 14):

I'd use [parse_url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) in the following way...

```
if ($urlParts = parse_url($myURI))
  $baseUrl = $urlParts["scheme"] . "://" . $urlParts["host"];
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use a regular expression:

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) && preg_match('@^[^/]+://[^/]+@', $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], $match)) {
    var_dump($match[0]);
}
```

Or you could use the [`parse_url` function](http://docs.php.net/parse_url).

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to use [the parse_url function](http://se.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) to achieve that