# how to get URL host using php

Tags: php, regex, url

I would like to get the host name of any url for example if i've the following url

```
$url = "http://www.google.com";
```

then i want to get only `google` what is after dot `.` and before extension dot `.` so that it can be applied for all types of urls.

so the results should be `google` ! i think this might needs regex or somehow
any idea how to do it , Thanks.

Comment: What if the URI has (sub)domains prefixed? i,e `http://office1.dept1.google.com`

Comment: Oops ! you are right that would fail on sub domains !

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try

```
echo __extractName("http://google.com"); 
echo __extractName("http://office1.dept1.google.com");
echo __extractName("http://google.co.uk");


function __extractName($url)
{
  $domain = parse_url($url , PHP_URL_HOST);
  if (preg_match('/(?P<domain>[a-z0-9][a-z0-9\-]{1,63}\.[a-z\.]{2,6})$/i', $domain, $list)) {
    return substr($list['domain'], 0,strpos($list['domain'], "."));
  }
  return false;
}
```

Output

```
google
google 
google
```

Comment: + 1, What about localhost without any domain alias?

Answer (score 2):

You should have a look at PHP's [parse_url()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) function which returns an associative array of the various components that constitute a URL.

```
$url = "http://www.google.com";
print_r(parse_url($url));
```

Will echo the following array.

```
Array ( [scheme] => http [host] => www.google.com )
```

The above function will just give you a start. Check into the following Stackoverflow archives on how to take it up from here.

[PHP Getting Domain Name From Subdomain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1201194/php-getting-domain-name-from-subdomain)

[Get domain name (not subdomain) in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2679618/get-domain-name-not-subdomain-in-php)

[PHP function to get the subdomain of a URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5292937/php-function-to-get-the-subdomain-of-a-url)

**EDIT** (few more archives - I'm not sure what you googled/tried)

[how to get domain name from URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/569137/how-to-get-domain-name-from-url/569219)

[Extract Scheme and Host from HTTP_REFERER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144856/how-do-i-split-serverhttp-referer-to-get-the-base-url)

Comment: Note that you can also pass `PHP_URL_HOST` as the second parameter, and it will just return the hostname instead of an array.

Comment: well based on your idea and very amazing archives, i will use 'explode' and then will results an array where i can print only the exact part of url i want. ~ thanks

Comment: for sure. Next time around, ensure that you "google" :) Lest you'll either be downvoted or your question will be closed.