# Make sure URL originates from same server

Tags: php, validation

Maybe I don't know how to phrase my searches properly, but this is what I need to do: Make sure that when a user clicks on my ad, it only comes from one particular site, otherwise returns false, or error.

```
FILTER_VALIDATE_URL
```

This only makes sure the URL is valid; I want to make sure it only originates from www.example.com or example.com, etc., but from nowhere else.

Comment: you can use the HTTP Referer Header but you cant rely on it, you should understand that http is a stateless protocol

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` then use PHP's `parse_url` function and use a condition for your url

ex:

```
$url = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];

if ( $parts = parse_url($url ) ) {
    $host = $parts[ "host" ];
if($host == 'www.example.com' || $host == 'example.com'){
  //... your action
}

}
```

reference: [Extract Scheme and Host from HTTP_REFERER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144856/extract-scheme-and-host-from-http-referer)

Comment: just as long as you don't mind that it wont always be correct.

Comment: @Dagon what do you mean sir?

Comment: you can never rely on  $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], it is browser set, and often stripped

Comment: Excuse my ignorance, but if I want it to come from www.example.com, or example.com only, this should work, right? Naked or not.

Comment: it will work some of the time. more than 50% but less than 100% i wouldn't want to be more specific than that.

Comment: Yeah, even PHP documentation says so. as of now I can't think of another way since we're just working on a browser. How about javascript's `document.referrer`?

Comment: Thank you both for your input, btw!

Comment: @JeremeCausing it is the same referrer part of the document header php\js no difference

Comment: welcome, I hope it answers your problem

Comment: Well I guess it's just the limitations in working on a browser. By the way have you tried the code above? just let us know if it worked for you.. :)

Comment: `<?php

$url = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];


if ($parts = parse_url($url)){

    $host = $parts["http://www.example.com"];

if($url == 'www.example.com' || $host == 'example.com'){

{

  header ("Location: http://www.anotherexample.com");

  }  

  else 

  {

   echo "URL is not valid";

}

}

?>`

Is what I'm trying to do.

Comment: I'm still trying to figure out how to comment properly with code...