# Find and print the host name of the mysql in wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, hostname

I am trying to find the **hostname** of the sql using wordpress. ie I wanted to print the '*localhost*' from `'http://**localhost**/velocity/wordpress/?page_id=4'`

I tried the *function **home_get_url()**,* but I got the entire path as shown above.
When I was trying with **gethostname()** I got my *PC name*. '

Please help. I am a *fresher to wordpress*.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Extract Scheme and Host from HTTP\_REFERER](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144856/extract-scheme-and-host-from-http-referer)

Comment: check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144856/extract-scheme-and-host-from-http-referer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`

For `http://localhost/velocity/wordpress/?page_id=4` it will return `http://localhost`

Comment: you have to do <?php echo site_url(); ?> when you want to print or get advantage of site url.

Comment: `site_url()` is function of `wordpress`.

Answer (score 1):

Hope it will help you .

```
printf("MySQL host info: %s\n", mysql_get_host_info());
```

You can also try .

```
<?php
echo gethostname(); // may output e.g,: sandie

// Or, an option that also works before PHP 5.3
echo php_uname('n'); // may output e.g,: sandie
?>
```

For more info .
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gethostname.php

Comment: Just FYI - `mysql_get_host_info()` is [deprecated](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-get-host-info.php) since `php>=7.0.0` use my `mysqli_get_host_info()` ( although I am not sure how to use in in wordpress when the `$link` parameter is needed . Would be interested to know ..